# GraphQL query is not returning the data at the first fetch itself

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo, graphql-js

In my NextJS application, I'm using Apollo Client to query the data. This is the code,

```
  //Redeem earnable item
  const claimableItemId = "5ab7c5ab-7a3d-4a92-a62f-2fbd995955f6";
  const destAddr = "0x387961b46242A42B445D4354d5048329410613a7";
  const [redeemEarnableItem, { data: redeemItem }] = useMutation(
    REDEEM_EARNABLE_ITEM,
    {
      variables: {
        claimableItemId,
        destAddr,
      },
    }
  );

  const {
    loading,
    error,
    data: invoiceDetails,
  } = useQuery(GET_INVOICE_DETAILS, {
    variables: { invoiceID: invoiceId ? invoiceId : null },
    skip: !invoiceId,
  });

  const redeemHandler = async () => {
    const redeemItem = await redeemEarnableItem();
    const id = redeemItem.data.redeemEarnableItem.invoiceID;
    setInvoiceId(id);
    const items = await invoiceDetails?.getInvoiceDetails?.items;
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (items) {
        console.log(items[items.length - 1], "details");
        const newItem = items[items.length - 1];
        setNFTDetails(newItem);
        setStep(STEPS.NFT_CLAIMED);
      }
    }, 2000);
  };
```

In the "redeemHandler" function, I'm trying to get the invoiceId from the mutation called "redeemEarnableItem" and pass it to the next query method called "GET_INVOICE_DETAILS" and get the invoiceDetails. When I run the "redeemHandler" function, the invoiceId is getting and passing as arguments to the GET_INVOICE_DETAILS query. But the "invoicedetails" is not coming at the 1st fetching. The data only comes when I run the redeemHandler function again. I'm trying to make the function to wait untill the data comes. But It's not working as I expected. Any help on this would be appreciated.